# SVG <mask>-Tag childs with css transform

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG-Document with an css stylesheet

```
mask .show { fill: white }
mask .hide { fill: black }

@keyframes resize {
    0% { transform: scaleX(.5) }
    50% { transform: scaleX(1.25) }
    100% { transform: scaleX(.5) }
}

mask .resize { animation: resize 10s ease infinite; transform-origin: 10px 50px }
```

and use masks

```
<mask id="oneMask">
    <rect class="show" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <ellipse class="hide resize" cx="10" cy="50" rx="10" ry="50" />
</mask>
```

this ellipse in that mask just become black, but not will be resize, what I want from it.

The CSS is working and the @keyframes to animate anything - everything but the `transform:` in CSS.

See here for [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usasVideos/jo197887/2/)

Please help me to animate and transform this with CSS, 
Thank You!!!

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: @alirezasafian As you can see, I've create an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usasVideos/jo197887/1/).

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work, please check it.

Comment: @alirezasafian You are right, but the problem is already their: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usasVideos/jo197887/2/)

Comment: Can you be more specific in what is not working. It is working for me in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7t7xv2/) The ellipse is scaling up then back down..

Comment: @StaceyBurns wich browser do you use? In the newest firefox css transforming is working, but on elements in masks transforming with css is not working.

Comment: I use chrome. Will take a look in Firefox later in the day. P.s your fiddle still isn't working. You need to remove those empty height and width attributes or give them a value.